# Depth-first search on a tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I understand the concept of *depth-first search* and I know exactly what it does. However, I can't understand this particular algorithm. Can someone give a short example on the basis of this algorithm?

> $\text{1. Initilisation: } S:=\{(w,0)\} \text{ and } R := \emptyset$
>
> $\text{2. Choose vertex: choose from $S$ a pair $p=(a,n)$ with a maximal
>  $n$}$
>
> $\text{3. Edit: $S := (S \setminus \{p\}) \space\cup \space \{(b,n+1)\space
>  |\space b \in a.children \}$ and $R:=R\space\cup\space\{ a \}; $ treat $a$}$
>
> $\text{4. Stop?: if $S = \emptyset $ stop else go to Choose vertex}$

Comment: What is the input? Choose a vertex from where? Is a $a$ vertex? number? Please provide the original algorithm, and some clarification

Comment: @TheHolyJoker The only thing noted is: A tree $T$ with root $w$ and set of vertices $V$.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker $a$ has to be a vertex I think.

Comment: Does it say **maximal** $n$ or **maximum** $n$? Have you tried any examples? If it does say maximum, the algorithm run on a trivial example is not well defined. The example: a tree with $3$ vertices, where the root is of degree 2.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker Thanks for pointing everything out. It is maximal.

Comment: I think $R$ is not a set, because I think there is meaning to the order in which elements are inserted to it. A solution I expect would be updating $R$ by $R=R\cup (a, n)$, or setting $R$ to be ordered set.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar algorithm in my AI course that makes this algorithm clear, you can see the algorithm below. The difference is that this algorithm does not make use of depth $n$.

When we compare this to the algorithm above, we can conclude that at first $S$ is a set that only contains the root $w$ with $0$ as its depth. Then we choose a vertex $a$ with maximal depth $n$ in $S$ and we will remove that vertex from $S$ and add the children of $a$ with depth $(n+1)$ to $S$. After that, $a$ will be added to the set $R$. We repeat this until the set $S$ is empty.

[image: alternative algorithm]